# C Unexpected Modulus Value

Tags: c, modulo

Here is a statement which I wanted to execute:

```
memoryPos = (memoryPos - 1) % memoryLen;
```

Info about variables:

- memoryPos is a long long int variable, containing 0.
- memoryLen is a size_t variable, containing 30000.

Running debugger,

```
(gdb) p memoryPos
$1 = 0
(gdb) p memoryLen
$2 = 30000
(gdb) p (memoryPos - 1) % memoryLen
$3 = 21615
(gdb) p (0 - 1) % 30000
$4 = -1
```

So somehow when computed with variables, it returns 21615, but I expected either a -1 or 29999.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is it's doing unsigned arithmetic.  `size_t` is a large unsigned integer type that's as large as `long long int`.  So it's treating `-1` as an unsigned value, i.e. a large power of two, minus one.  You can fix it by forcing the first operand to be positive by adding `memoryLen` to it, i.e.

```
memoryPos = (memoryLen + memoryPos - 1) % memoryLen;
```

That should give you the answer you're looking for.